# How to add markers on top of a polygon using Google Maps Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API, and I've defined a polygon and attached it to a map:

```
const region = new google.maps.Polygon({
  map: map,
  paths: [
    { lat: 40.5577151228437, lng: -74.15980859374997 },
    { lat: 40.599436503265856, lng: -74.27516503906247 },
    { lat: 40.67030312529891, lng: -74.25319238281247 },
    { lat: 40.72548139969253, lng: -74.26079167357881 },
  ],
});
```

I have a click handler that adds a marker on it when the user clicks:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: e.latLng,
    });
  });
```

I see the marker when I click on areas **outside** of the polygon, but I **don't see the marker when I click inside the polygon**.

I've tried hard-coding a zIndex on each, but no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. add a click listener to the polygon

```
google.maps.event.addListener(region, 'click', function (e) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: e.latLng,
    });
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dcyp7f6u/3/)

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  const region = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: [
      { lat: 40.5577151228437, lng: -74.15980859374997 },
      { lat: 40.599436503265856, lng: -74.27516503906247 },
      { lat: 40.67030312529891, lng: -74.25319238281247 },
      { lat: 40.72548139969253, lng: -74.26079167357881 },
    ],
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < region.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(region.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  function addMarker(e) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: e.latLng,
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addMarker);
  google.maps.event.addListener(region, 'click', addMarker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

2. make the polygon not capture clicks (clickable: false);

```
const region = new google.maps.Polygon({
  map: map,
  clickable: false,
  paths: [
    { lat: 40.5577151228437, long: -74.15980859374997 },
    { lat: 40.599436503265856, long: -74.27516503906247 },
    { lat: 40.67030312529891, long: -74.25319238281247 },
    { lat: 40.72548139969253, long: -74.26079167357881 },
  ],
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dcyp7f6u/2/)

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  const region = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    clickable: false,
    paths: [
      { lat: 40.5577151228437, lng: -74.15980859374997 },
      { lat: 40.599436503265856, lng: -74.27516503906247 },
      { lat: 40.67030312529891, lng: -74.25319238281247 },
      { lat: 40.72548139969253, lng: -74.26079167357881 },
    ],
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < region.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(region.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: e.latLng,
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```